# Scrape Google after setting location

Tags: python, search, location

First I would like to point out, that I'm not aiming for thousands of result here, I'm only interested in the first page to make some stats.

I've tried using mechanize to set the location in the preferences, but I always get and error.

```
br.open('https://www.google.ca/preferences?hl=en-CA&fg=1#location')

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['luul'] = 'Toronto, Canada'

resp = br.submit()
```

I get the global preferences page and this error:

> The location Toronto, Canada was not recognized.

I tried to query https://www.google.ca/preferences?hl=en&muul=4_20&luul=Toronto,+Canada&prev=https://www.google.ca&gbv=1&sei=XXX, but no luck.

Comment: I keep getting `request disallowed by robots.txt` error. I assume google disabled the use of scripts connecting to their site. Could be wrong though

Comment: I do get a response, I get the preferences page with the error message.

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether you get a response or not, I was saying what response I get. So I can't help you beyond telling you what response I get and the conclusion I draw from the response that I get. Sorry

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to mention, that I have also set my user agent: 
    `br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.3')]`

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem, did you find any kind of solution?

Comment: I just decided to use CasperJS, it works great!